# Can I ask questions regarding suggesting Android phones with specifications that I mention?

Tags: support, scope

I'm currently looking forward to buying a new phone. I'm not sure if asking here is appropriate or not, so I decided to ask on this meta post.

I am aware that I should't ask too broad or primarily opinion based questions here. I checked out [Can we ask for genuine reviews of an Android Phone here?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/can-we-ask-for-genuine-reviews-of-an-android-phone-here) and it was mentioned there:

> This is because shopping questions have no one definite answer, and as such are a bad fit for a question/answer site. Each user has their own preferences and use patterns, and therefore the answers can't be really considered universal.

If suppose I did mention what I require in a phone, and give a priority to what properties I prefer in a phone, would it be reasonable to ask here? I always prefer to ask neat and clean questions with no ambiguity. I refrain from asking vague questions like "What's the best android phone under ₹15k?", but rather I prefer to ask questions like "Can anyone suggest phones with over 13MP camera and over 3GB RAM?".

IF these questions are inappropriate here, where can I ask them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Asking for software or hardware recommendations is off-topic here. For the former, we have a sister-site specialist on Software Recommendations – see [Where to ask for app recommendations?](/q/2060/16575) For the latter, there's another sister site called [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) you should look at – as it falls into the category of [Shopping recommendations](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/164/16575), which are (as stated) off-topic at Android.SE. Note however that, as [Is it on topic to ask for help choosing a suitable Android device?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2124/16575) points out, they have a specific understanding on [what counts as "high-quality" on that site](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality/206#206).